# Interfacing ADC with MCU using SCI

Tags: microcontroller, adc, interface

I am trying to interface a Texas Instruments (TI) 16-bit ADC to a TI Piccolo microcontroller (MCU) via a serial communication interface (SCI). The ADC block diagram shows 3 connections for this; a Data Out, a SCLK, and a CS.

The Piccolo MCU has an SCIRX and SCITX connection for SCI interfacing. The CS connection I am sure I can take from any GPIO (right?). My main question is what do I hook up to the ADC SCLK input? The only clock outputs from the MCU that I can see are the SPICLK outputs, but thats a different interface.

Please advice.

-D

Comment: SCI is a UART. Are you sure you wouldn't rather use SPI?

Comment: The ADC states it is SPI/DSP compatible, so I think the question is answered. If I have further hiccups I will post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ADC states it is SPI/DSP compatible, so I think the question is answered. If I have further hiccups I will post. Thanks.